# Upgrading to DNN version 7.02.02 issue

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am upgrading a website from the DNN version 6.02.08 to 7.02.02 and I am receiving the following error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'ClientDependency.Core' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

When I researched the error I found that this is associated with the version of ASP.NET that is running. The suggested fix for the error was to update the .NET version to at least 4.0. But when I went into the properties of the website on Visual Studio it looks like it is already running 4.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would upgrade your web server to support .NET 4.5 (available via windows update) and I believe that will resolve your problem.